# Showing this set in linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

> Being $V$ a linear space of $\Bbb K$. Show that if $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are vectors of $V$ and $_1, _2, _3 ∈ $ then the set $${_2v_3 − _3v_2, _1v_2 − _2v_1, _3v_1 − _1v_3}$$
>   is linearly dependent.

My attempt:

If the set is linearly dependent then there are scalars $\beta1$ $\beta2$ and $\beta3$ not all zero that:
$$\beta_1(_2v_3 − _3v_2) + \beta_2(_1v_2 − _2v_1) + \beta_3(_3v_1 − _1v_3) = 0 $$

I started solving the equation and I decided to isolate $v_3$, so that I can write that I can express $v_3$ as a linear combination of $v_2$ and $v_1$. But for that $\beta_1\alpha_2 + \beta_3\alpha_1$ might be different that zero $\dots$

But how can I justify that?

Comment: Let $v_1 = v_2 = v_3 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

My thought: Can I write the thirs vector as a linear combination of the first two? Where to start: The scalar of $v_3$ in the third vector is $α_3$ but in the first vector it is $α_2$. So let's multiply the first vector by $\frac{α_3}{α_2}$ assuming that $α_2\neq 0$. Then repeat for $v_1$ and the second vector and see if it works (which it does): $$α_3v_1-α_1v_3=-\frac{α_1}{α_2}(α_2v_3-α_3v_2)-\frac{α_3}{α_2}(α_1v_2-α_2v_1)$$ if of course $α_2\neq 0$. Else...

Comment: Ok I understood your proof but how can I conclude that alfa 2 is zero?

Comment: Hmm, you cannot conclude that $\alpha_2=0$ and this is not implied nowhere in the answer. So seemingly you did not understand my proof

Comment: *is not zero was what i meant, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Since it's possible that $\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3$ are linearly independent vectors, we want to solve for $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ in terms of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ subject to the constraints that:
$$\begin{cases}
\alpha_3\beta_3 - \alpha_2\beta_2 = 0 \\
\alpha_1\beta_2 - \alpha_3\beta_1 = 0 \\
\alpha_2\beta_1 - \alpha_1\beta_3 = 0
\end{cases}$$
By inspection, note that we can choose:
$$\begin{cases}
\beta_1 = \alpha_1 \\
\beta_2 = \alpha_3 \\
\beta_3 = \alpha_2
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Right, so if I choose those values for my beta I will get the zero vector and all the betas are not zero so my set in linearly dependent, right?

Comment: Right. If we assume instead that all the betas are zero, then all the alphas are zero, so the given set contains only the zero vector and so is still linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the first by $a_1$ then you get $a_2a_1v_3-a_3a_1v_2$. Multiply the second by $a_3$ then you get $a_1a_3v_2-a_2a_3v_1$. Summing you obtain $a_2(a_1v_3-a_3v_1)$. If $a_2=0$ the set is trivially dependend because the first vector is $a_1v_2$ and the second is $a_3v_2$. If not, then
$$\frac{a_1}{a_2}(a_2v_3-a_3v_2)+\frac{a_3}{a_2}(a_1v_2-a_2v_1)=a_1v_3-a_3v_1$$